# API Error response when creating a request transaction: Missing parameter: `type`

Tags: coinbase-api, coinbase-php

When creating the transaction using the Coinbase PHP Library I am getting the following error from the API; Missing parameter: `type`

I added debug statements to double check that the library is properly sending the type, which it is.

```
type: "request",
amount: "10",
description: "random string",
to: "test@email.com",
currency: "BTC"
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue recently? I'm thinking that it's currently an issue with the coinbase API.

Ran down the rabbit hole making sure that it is properly sending the type properly to the API

```php
$transaction = Transaction::request([
                'toEmail' => 'test@email.com',
                'amount' => new Money(1, 'BTC'),
                'description' => 'Test transaction'
            ]);
            $client->createAccountTransaction($client->getPrimaryAccount(), $transaction);
```

Result:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "Missing parameter: `type`"
}
```

Expected:

JSON data including information about the request

Comment: have you got the solution of this problem?

Comment: This is still happening it seems - looks like a bug on their backed (which isn't anything unusual)

Comment: Has anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is an API bug ... not a php/python... bug